# Ubuntu 13.04 screen calibration Panasonic toughbook CF30

Tags: 13.04, touchscreen

I am having problems keeping the touch screen calibrated after each restart. I have used this guide: http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-ubuntu-1204-touchscreen-calibration and have done and triple checked everything. Can you help? Thank you.